# Rich text web editor with numbers and letters in outline

Tags: javascript, richtext

I have a CakePHP page with a standard rich text editor using a javascript library. It works great, but my client needs to have letters and numbers in outlines.

For example. What I want to see:
1. Line one
    a. sub-point
2. Line two
    a. more info
    b. even more info

But this is the only option I have found:
1. Line one
    1. sub-point
2. Line two
    1. more info
    2. even more info

Or, bullet points.

Does anyone know of a library that allows numbers and letters? My client is willing to pay for a premium library.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is the wrong place for such questions, as they are considered offtopic. That being said **http://ckeditor.com**, **http://ckeditor.com/addon/liststyle**

Comment: oops, sorry to post in the wrong place. Thanks for the link to ckeditor.com That one has the same problem I mentioned. It only allows numbers or bullet points in an outline.

Comment: Check the linked addon description, it supports "[...] _circle, square, dot for bulleted list or decimal, lower/upper roman, lower/upper alpha for numbered list_ [...]".